# Is it possible to look up a texel from a texture in GLES2 GLSL framgent shader without using sampler?

Tags: textures, glsl, opengl-es2, fragment-shader

Is there some way I can **directly access texture memory** from **fragment shader** in `GLES2` `GLSL`? I don't need the sampler to be involved since I am just using it as a **look-up table**.

Comment: Err? I don't really understand your question. What you describe (i.e. accessing texture memory) is actually what a sampler is meant to do. What do you think is a sampler doing?

Comment: @Mario You can access textures without samplers in SM4+ IIRC (e.g. HLSL Load()). I doubt this is possible in ES2 though.

Comment: @JarkkoL Okay, interesting. Didn't do anything with newer versions so far. Is it just different syntax or is there some other (dis-)advantage?

Comment: @Mario: The sampler is nice when you want to have mip-mapping, filtering and all sorts of other directly graphics related enhancements, but these will cost extra performance and may add implementation specific artifacts when you are trying to use the texture as a look-up-table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[texelFetch](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/texelFetch.xhtml) is used for lockups without performing mip-mappnig, filtering..etc. and even with this you still need to pass a sampler.

Otherwise your out of luck, as far as I am aware, making such operation available restricts driver writers from doing certain optimization, for instance they need to keep textures in a certain layout in memory.

Comment: That requires an extension in gles2 right?

Comment: @LennartRolland Yes, unfortunately.